# Scrape Text Between Two Strong Tags

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape "167" (top right) from the following website: https://www.goodfirms.co/billing-invoicing-software/.

I can manage to get all of the text, but I'm just trying to get the numbers, and I am not sure on how to isolate it. Would someone be able to help me?

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import requests_random_user_agent

s = requests.Session()
user_agent = s.headers['User-Agent']

headers = {
'accept': '*/*',
'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.7,ru;q=0.6',
'referer': 'https://www.google.com/',
'connection': 'Keep-alive',
'user-agent': user_agent,
}

response = requests.get('https://www.goodfirms.co/billing-invoicing-software/', headers=headers)

soup = bs(response.content, 'lxml')

test = soup.find("section", class_="section-breadcrumb blog-breadcrumb overflow").text

print(test)
```

Output:

```
Home >
Billing and Invoicing Software
167 Softwares  |  Last updated: Jul 31, 2022
```

Desired output:

```
167
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number `167` is located under tag with class `class="last_update` inside `<strong>` tag:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.goodfirms.co/billing-invoicing-software/"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

num = soup.select_one(".last_update strong")
print(num.text)
```

Prints:

```
167
```